# Migrating from OFORK to any other ticket system

Tags: migration, otrs, ticket-system, zammad

**I use OFORK 10.0.5 and would like to switch to a different ticket system.**
I would like to take my data with me.

For example, I find a migration tool from Zammad for OTRS.
But not for OFORK.

Has anyone already migrated from OFORK to another system or even an idea how to get from it to another system?

---

I tried using “Znuny4OTRS-ZammadMigrator 6.0.7” to initiate the migration to Zammad.:
[Znuny4OTRS-ZammadMigrator 6.0.7 package information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O5l1.png)

There is a newer version of OFORK (10.0.6) that doesn't work either.